# javascript: force no frames and POST?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to force removal of surrounding frames on page load:
onLoad="if(parent.frames.length!=0)top.location='pagename.html';"

I'm wondering if I can combine this with a post request (I have an iFrame that submits that won't work with target="_top", so I'm redirecting to an intermediary page, and want to remove the frames with above code but keep the data sending through to the final page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think redirects via META tags, JavaScript, or HTTP have to be GET requests. You could have pagename.html resubmit as POST via AJAX if it's loaded as a GET request, though.